# url being appended to redirect link htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file whenever I create 301 redirects, the url to be redirected from is appended to the url to be redirected to. For example:

```
Redirect /linksresources.html http://example.com/resources/
```

Will redirect me to:

```
http://example.com/resources/?/linksresources.html
```

The existing .htaccess file:

```
#404 Custom Error page
#ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/404.php

#force IE out of compatibility mode
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

#Disable Indexing
Options -Indexes 


Order Deny,Allow
Allow from All




Redirect /linksresources.html http://example.com/resources/



RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

#if request is not an existing file or directory then redirect to
#codeigniter boot.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ boot.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I feel like I have resolved this issue in the past, but I can not remember what it was that I did. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a conflict with your mod_rewrite directives, which are executing *before* the mod_alias `Redirect` directive, despite the apparent order in your config file. Different modules execute at different times during the request. For this reason, it is not recommended to mix redirects from both modules.

Specifically, the existing `RewriteRule` is being triggered since presumably `/linksresource.html` does not exist as a physical file and is being internally rewritten to `boot.php?/linksresource.html`. The mod_alias `Redirect` then fires, matching `/linksresource.html` against the *original request* and redirects to `http://example.com/resources/?/linksresources.html` - passing the query string through from the rewritten request.

Since you are already using mod_rewrite, you should change the mod_alias `Redirect` to the equivalent mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^linksresources\.html$ http://example.com/resources/ [R=302,L]
```